# Tableview Controller invalid update only occurs when logged in with one specific user

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

When the User gest to this Tableview Controller in the ViewDidLoad the table is updated with all current existing users and their usernames. This works fine when I am logged in with one of my two user. However as soon as I log in with the user the app crashes when I get to this TablewViewController. 
I have no idea why. The snapshot of the observed data is correct.

This is the code:

```
databaseRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    let key = snapshot.key
    let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    self.usersArray.append(snapshot)
        print(snapshot)
        if key == self.loggedInUser?.uid {

            print("same as logged in user")

        }else {
        // insert rows

        self.FindFriendsTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1, section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

        }
        })

        { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

although the if statement gives back true by printing out "same as logged in user", the app crashes in the else statement, which confuses me. This is the shown error:

'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Has anyone any idea why that does happen and even more specific why that only happens to one user?